# AndEngine registerEntityModifier is not working

Tags: android, andengine

Im trying to make simple puzzle game using AndEngine. Everything was wokring fine till I got this strange issue.

I have a function to move the sprite in the scene as below.

```
private void placeSprite(final float touchX, final float touchY) {
        float posX = selectedSprite.getX();
        float posY = selectedSprite.getY();
        moveModifier = new MoveModifier(0.25f, posX, posY, touchX, touchY);
        selectedSprite.registerEntityModifier(moveModifier);}
```

I was using this function to move sprite and was working perfectly.

But when I tried to call this function from a handler, sprite is not moved.
There is no any error displayed in LogCat.

Below is my handler:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            switch (msg.arg1) {

        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            // other functions
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            //function is called here.
            placeSprite(400f,200f);
            break;

        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            //other functions
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

I dont know why same code works if called from other thread but doesnt work if called from above handler.

I also found that main cause is **registerEntityModifier** was not working. I also want to know in what cases **registerEntityModifier** doesnt work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should call this method from *Update* thread not everywhere else.

```
mEngine.runOnUpdateThread((new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        placeSprite(400f,200f);        
    }
});
```